# google analytics funnel visualisation vs google Reporting API goal values

Tags: google-analytics

I am issues reconciling goal values from funnel visualisation and getting the data from google API.

The results via google API are completely different.

[image]

ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-07-24&end-date=2015-07-24&metrics=ga%3Agoal14Starts%2Cga%3Agoal14Completions

Note: filtering has been done for the same date. (2015-07-24)